# Unexplained crash during AVPlayer playback

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, crash, avplayer

I have a UIViewController which contains an AVPlayer showing a movie.

I've coded a pair of buttons to allow skipping forward and backwards to certain points in the video.

After 12 clicks of either of these buttons, my app crashes.

I've tried running instruments and there is no leaking objects when the buttons are clicked.  The allocations sit at around 14-15MB.  When debugging, the app doesn't even break.

Does anyone have any advice on how to isolate the problem?  Any advice at all on tracking down crashes which are obviously memory related but don't cause the app to break during debug.

Thanks in advance.

Duncan

Answer (score 0):

Try running your app with NSZombieEnabled ? Click on the scheme drop down bar goto edit scheme and in arguments tab add NSZombieEnabled in the Environment Variables column and set its value to YES. When using a zombie, any message sent to an object that has already released will result in an exception.

Comment: Thanks MSK.  Just tried that and no difference.  App crashes without breaking.  I don't think it's a problem with a released object being called because the button works fine for the first 11 clicks.  It's almost like the whole app is running out of memory and just crashing without stopping in debug.

Comment: Did you overridden "didReceiveMemoryWarning" in your app delegate (and viewcontrollers) ? Make sure to release as much memory as possible. I noticed in my app that sometime iOS did not call didReceiveMemoryWarning before killing the app. NSLog in these methods to make sure that memory is not the problem here.

Comment: OK.  So in the didReceiveMemoryWarning overrides I should set everything to nil?  I'll try that now.  Thanks.

Comment: You should release any memory that you can. E.g. [myCachedImage release] or myImageView.image = nil; or [myCachedDictiomary release]; You should check if you are getting memory warnings first by NSLogging.